# vpnc: vpnc.c:1166: lifetime_ike_process: Assertion `0' failed

Tags: linux, vpn

I have on a Fritzbox configured a VPN access. Now I'm trying to setup a VPN client on a CentOS 6 machine. For that I have installed vpnc and NetworkManager-vpnc and I'm following the description at http://tosit.de/aktuelles/vpn-verbindung-unter-ubuntu-zu-fritzbox.html

But every time if I trying to connecting the VPN (from command line "vpnc") I get the error

```
vpnc: vpnc.c:1166: lifetime_ike_process: Assertion `0' failed.
```

Also if I try it with the networkManager with enabled debug output (nm-vpnc-service --debug) I get:

```
** Message: <info>  vpnc started with pid 13161

vpnc: vpnc.c:1166: lifetime_ike_process: Assertion `0' failed.

** (process:13150): WARNING **: <WARN>  vpnc_watch_cb(): vpnc died with signal 6
```

In /var/log/message (client side) I get:

```
Dec 18 19:02:30 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc'...
Dec 18 19:02:30 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 13282
Dec 18 19:02:30 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc' appeared, activating connections
Dec 18 19:02:30 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 1
Dec 18 19:02:35 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
Dec 18 19:02:35 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> VPN connection 'Fritzbox test' (Connect) reply received.
Dec 18 19:02:35 lifebook01 kernel: tun0: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Dec 18 19:02:35 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 6
Dec 18 19:02:35 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Dec 18 19:02:35 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Dec 18 19:02:35 lifebook01 NetworkManager[12964]: <info> Policy set 'System eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
```

Anybody knows what's the problem here or how can I get a better error message?